# How to create reorderable grid view with custom height in flutter?

Tags: flutter, gridview, draggable, reorderable-list

[image]

Grid view items should be draggable and with custom heights.
Edit: Items should have kept their size.

Comment: Would also like to figure this out! If you find out let me know!

Answer (score 1):

try [reorderableitemsview](https://pub.dev/packages/reorderableitemsview):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:reorderableitemsview/reorderableitemsview.dart';

class GridPageView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GridPageViewState createState() => _GridPageViewState();
}

class _GridPageViewState extends State<GridPageView> {

  List<StaggeredTileExtended> _listStaggeredTileExtended = <StaggeredTileExtended>[
    StaggeredTileExtended.count(2, 2),
    StaggeredTileExtended.count(2, 1),
    StaggeredTileExtended.count(1, 2),
    StaggeredTileExtended.count(1, 1),
    StaggeredTileExtended.count(2, 2),
    StaggeredTileExtended.count(1, 2),
    StaggeredTileExtended.count(1, 1),
    StaggeredTileExtended.count(3, 1),
    StaggeredTileExtended.count(1, 1),
    StaggeredTileExtended.count(4, 1),
  ];

  List<Widget> _tiles = <Widget>[
    _Example01Tile(Key("a"),Colors.green, Icons.widgets),
    _Example01Tile(Key("b"),Colors.lightBlue, Icons.wifi),
    _Example01Tile(Key("c"),Colors.amber, Icons.panorama_wide_angle),
    _Example01Tile(Key("d"),Colors.brown, Icons.map),
    _Example01Tile(Key("e"),Colors.deepOrange, Icons.send),
    _Example01Tile(Key("f"),Colors.indigo, Icons.airline_seat_flat),
    _Example01Tile(Key("g"),Colors.red, Icons.bluetooth),
    _Example01Tile(Key("h"),Colors.pink, Icons.battery_alert),
    _Example01Tile(Key("i"),Colors.purple, Icons.desktop_windows),
    _Example01Tile(Key("j"),Colors.blue, Icons.radio),
  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("List Demo"),
      ),
      body: ReorderableItemsView(
        onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
          setState(() {
            _tiles.insert(newIndex, _tiles.removeAt(oldIndex));
          });
        },
        children: _tiles,
        crossAxisCount: 4,
        isGrid: true,
        staggeredTiles: _listStaggeredTileExtended,
        longPressToDrag: false,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _Example01Tile extends StatelessWidget {
  _Example01Tile(Key key, this.backgroundColor, this.iconData): super(key: key);

  final Color backgroundColor;
  final IconData iconData;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Card(
      color: backgroundColor,
      child: new InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: new Center(
          child: new Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            child: new Icon(
              iconData,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case, items should have kept their size.

Comment: What do you mean by "kept their size", you can still create 2 column with different height items~